# How to open 2nd project in browser when using Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

I'm using Webstorm for my phaser game development. It's been ok up till now but now I'm a tad confused as to how I've got things set up.

I've got a project called say myGame1, and when I run the index page it opens up like this in the browser

```
http://localhost:63342/myGame1/index.html
```

And that runs fine.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to set things up so I can have another game project open as well, and open that games index page as well in the browser. Because when I try to do that, it just opens the previous game still.

I think it's got something to do with configurations, I've tried to set up another one but when I try to use that config it just says error 404 when opening in a browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, title updated.

Comment: do you have several projects with the same name (myGame1)?  The built-in web server where the pages are hosted by default uses the following URL: localhost:63342/project_name/file_name.html. And if the projects are same-named, on opening pages from other projects server attempts to load them from the first project directory and fails